# Canvas + Angular 5 requestAnimationFrame Crashing

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, canvas

I've been trying to animate some items on canvas in Angular v5.2.10 by using canvas on a single component and been having problems with requestAnimationFrame.

For the first 4000 frames that are logged in console.log() the animation  runs smoothly. After 8000 frames the app crashes. I've generated a simple app with angula cli v1.6.7 and added this component and this still crashes the app after 8000 frames logged.

I'm new to canvas and ran this app in Vanillajs and it was fine. Is there anything I'm missing when animating canvas on Angular?

I appreciate any Feedback.

### Here's the code to my components.

animation.component.ts:

```
  @ViewChild('myCanvas') canvas: ElementRef;
  public ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  width: number = 320;
  height: number = 480;

  frames: number = 0;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.main();
  } 

  main(){
    this.ctx = <HTMLCanvasElement>this.canvas.nativeElement).getContext('2d');
      // run Game
    this.run();
  }

  run(){
    this.update();
    this.render();

    requestAnimationFrame(()=> this.run());
  }

  update(){
    console.log(this.frames);
    this.frames++;
  }

  render(){
   // Image would render here
  }
```

animation.component.html

```
<canvas 
    #myCanvas width={{width}} height={{height}}></canvas>
```

**Update**: I've tested this with Heap snapshot to check for memory leaks but no change happens when the app is at frame 0 and frame 5000

**Update**: I've setup the RequestAnimationFrame to run outside zone.js like show here. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8401.

```
this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => { 
 let loop = () => {       
    this.update();         
    this.render();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);    

  };

  requestAnimationFrame(loop);  
}
```

But still Animation crashes on frame 8000.

Comment: Although you do not mention specifics of the crash,this has to be a stack overflow. See [MDN - requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), you need some condition to terminate the recursive call. In their example it is `if (progress < 2000) {...}`

Comment: I agree that this has to be a stack overflow. But setting up a limit is not a possibility since this is going to animate a game. The animation will continue indefinitely if the user does not click on it. My guess is that this has something to do with zones being created in each iteration and not been destroyed.

Comment: I've recreated the bug here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/canvas-bug-requestanimationframe?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts